# The area of the set in which a polynomial is "small"

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Prove that there exist a constant $C$ such that for every *monic* polynomial $P$, the area of the set $A=\{x : |P(x)|<1\}$ is at most $C$.

Remarks:

1. This puzzle holds for both the real and the complex field (with possibly different $C$'s)
2. Monic polynomial means that the leading coefficient is 1

Comment: Just look up Remez inequality for the real case and the Cartan lemma for the complex case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a famous result by Pólya.

G. Pólya, Beitrag zur Verallgemeinerung des Verzerrungssatzes auf mehrfach zusammenhängende Gebiete, Sitzungsberichte Akad. Wiss. Berlin (1928), 228–232 & 280–282. Also in volume 1 of Pólya’s Collected Papers, MIT press, (1974).

For a modern account and a generalization, see Edward Crane, [The Area of Polynomial Images and Preimages](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302189.pdf).